# Where did Peirce publish his triadic model of signs?

Tags: history, philosophy-of-language, semiotics

A triadic model of signs can be found by various researchers. Probably the most famous illustration is the diagram in Ogden and Richards's *The Meaning of Meaning* (page 11, [digitized here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOgden_semiotic_triangle.png)). It is also attributed to Peirce as one of the two founders of semiotics, who writes:

> The thing having this character I term a *representamen*, the mental effect, or thought, its *interpretant*, the thing for which it stands, its *object*.

The most common reference I could found is in the *Collected Papers of Charles Sanders Peirce*, volume 1, paragraph 564 ([digitized here](http://books.google.de/books?id=HoRfcRUtpnEC&pg=PA303&dq=%22The%20thing%20having%20this%20character%20I%20term%20a%20representamen,%20the%20mental%20effect,%20or%20thought,its%20interpretant,%20the%20thing%20for%20which%20it%20stands,%20its%20object%22), often cited from 1932, but it seems to be published first in 1931). The original paper is *On a New List of Categories*, first published in 1867 in the *Proceedings of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences* (pages 287-298). This paper, however, does **not** include the triadic model, but Peirce added it later to the version printed in the collected papers. Peirce died in 1914, so obviously he has written it before, but where? People seem to just copy references without having looked for the original, don't they? ;-)

Comment: I have  a number of his works at home. I'll do a little digging. As for your remark on copying references, yes, people do that. Two papers that support your point are: http://www.jstor.org/pss/2632315 and http://www.jstor.org/pss/170961

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find the reference you need in this paper by [Paul Weiss and Arthur Burks](https://www.pdcnet.org/pdc/bvdb.nsf/purchase?openform&fp=jphil&id=jphil_1945_0042_0014_0383_0388), "Peirce's Sixty-Six Signs", *The Journal of Philosophy*, Volume 42, Issue 14, July 1945 [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2019195)
The authors make a detailed presentation of various attempts made by Peirce to classify signs. The triadic approach was just one of them. All the relevant references to Peirce's *Collected Papers* are provided.